# How to undelete a field in MSCRM entities

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am trying to add a field to my entity call abc_salespersonname when I try to add it I am presented with duplicate field name.
The field does not show in the solutions entity field list but I can see it in the database.
I do know that when you delete a field from an entity, it does not actually delete from the database.
So my question is, how can I bring this field in the database back onto the entity.

Comment: Confusing. Can you show some screenshot?

Comment: I do not think there is a supported way to do this. I've always just used a new name.

Comment: @ArunVinoth unfortunately I cannot due to security issue with work.

Comment: What CRM version ?

Comment: Does it show in the customisations area? I.e. when you are looking at all customisations, rather than a specific solution?

Comment: No it doesn't. The field was deleted, but MSCRM seems to just hide fields rather than actually delete them.

Comment: You mention 'solutions entity field list' if this field existed in an unmanaged solution, the customization will still exist in your organization. Make sure to go to the customizations page instead and delete the field from there.

Comment: No, it has been deleted from both solution and customisations and it still exists in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot Undelete any field in a supported way. Once deleted is deleted, gone forever.

Not sure, if you are mixed up with “Remove” & “Delete” options within solution sub-components. Atleast “Publish All Customizations” will make all the database schema, Metadata & UI in sync. Verify the default solution by going to Settings->Customizations->Customize the system to double check.

If you are seeing duplicate field name alert, then you cannot bypass it. Create a new field with different name & move forward.